# Laravel tests are not saving factories to database

Tags: laravel, api, testing, phpunit

I'm having trouble with testing in that the records of my factories are not being saved to the database for my API tests. Here is an example test

```
use DatabaseTransactions;

public function testUserMe()
{
    $user = factory(\App\Models\User::class, 'userA')->create();
    $token = factory(\App\Models\ApiToken::class, 'userA-token')->create();

    $this->refreshApplication(); // I've tried with and without this line

    $headers = ['HTTP_Authorization' => 'Bearer '. $token->token];

    $this->json('GET', '/user/me', [], $headers, $headers)
         ->assertJson([
             'first_name' => $user->first_name,
             'last_name' => $user->last_name,
             'email' => $user->email,
         ])
         ->assertStatus(200);
}
```

Note: I have `$headers` in the request twice as I'm seeing inconsistencies in examples but this is irrelevant to the issues.

The issue I'm having is that the middleware is failing as the user and token have not been committed to the database. If I remove the `use DatabaseTransactions` it will work as expected (middleware works and tests pass) but the data is not cleared after the test.

I have the exact same thing working on a previous project with what I think is the same setup, including the lack of use of `setup()` and `teardown()`. Does anyone have some ideas on where else I can look?

Why would `use DatabaseTransactions` be preventing the records being created?

Comment: Is the database seeded correctly before running the tests?

Comment: No, I don't think it is. I saw such an issue* being discussed about Laravel 5.1 and saw that it was fixed. I am using 5.4. Do you think it's the same issue?   *https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/testing/databasetransactions-databasemigrations-have-no-effect

Comment: Not the same issue i guess. `DatabaseTransactions` doesn't run migrations for you. So you need to at least create the structure before the tests. But its weird it runs correctly without `DatabaseTransactions`

Comment: The issues do seem similar in that the tests are running before the data is being saved to the database. However I don't have a lot of time right now to dig right into the code to debug it to the same level.

Comment: Update: I can see from the MySQL log and more debugging that the records are being saved to the database and rolling back. I assume they're rolling back before the test is complete.